# gsutil: specify project on copy

Tags: gsutil

I'm attempting to come up with commands to facilitate deployment to different environments (production, staging) in my GCP project using gsutil.

The following deploys to production without issue:

```
gsutil cp -r ./build/* gs://<production-project-name>/
```

I'd like to deploy to a bucket in another project.  The gsutil help page alludes to a `-p` option for `ls` and `mb` used to change the project context of the gsutil command.

I'd like to use a command like this to deploy my app to a staging environment:

```
gsutil cp -r ./build/* gs://<existing-bucket-in-staging-project>/ -p <staging-project-name>
```

Alas, the -p option is not available for the `cp` command.  I confirmed on the [gsutil cp doc page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp).

What is the best way to deploy a build artifact to a Google Cloud storage bucket to a bucket in a project other than the one currently specified in the terminal environment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bucket namespace is global, so as long as the credentials you're using have permission to the other project, you shouldn't need a project parameter with the `cp` command.  In other words, this command should work fine:

```
gsutil cp -r ./build/* gs://<bucket-in-staging-project>
```